# JPanels to appear on every GUI i have created

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel

How do i have the JPanels in the Mainframe to appear on all other GUI i've created?
Do i have to make the same JPanels in the Mainframe again or is there another way to make it as a fixed layout so i can only edit the content part?

Comment: Please give us more details on your goal and your problems you are having solving it. Note that a component can only appear in one container at a time. Also, does your program have multiple JFrames? If so, you may be best off re-thinking your program design.

Comment: i'm creating an application with a fixed desgin. So i have everything fixed in the Mainframe (the navigaion bar), So how do i have the navigation bar to appear on other JPanels for other GUI? I only have one JFrame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You state in comment:

> i'm creating an application with a fixed desgin. So i have everything fixed in the Mainframe (the navigaion bar), So how do i have the navigation bar to appear on other JPanels for other GUI? I only have one JFrame.

I wouldn't have the same navigation bar appear in multiple JPanes, but rather would place my navigationBar in the main JFrame's contentPane in a fixed position, say in the BorderLayout.PAGE_START spot, and then swap my JPanel "views" in the BorderLayout.CENTER position using a CardLayout. This way only one navigationBar need be made, and it would be visible all the time (unless you explicitly choose not to show it).